# Deserialize / parse an object with keyvalue to an object without key in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The API I use returns a JSON object with the following map structure. I want to parse the object so that the index moves from the key to an object property. I have tried a few things, but right now I'm not getting anywhere. The problem is that I cannot manage to assign only the entries of the object without the key.

```
private parse(item: Item): Item {
  // parsing
  return parsedItem;
}
```

The item looks like:

```
{
  "0": {
    "prop1": "hello",
    "prob2": "test"
  }
}
```

The object I want:

```
{
  "key": 0,
  "prop1": "hello",
  "prob2": "test"
}
```

Comment: what if there are more objects ,like {
  "0": {
    "prop1": "hello",
    "prob2": "test"
  },"1": {
    "prop1": "hello",
    "prob2": "test"
  },
} how should be the output....should it be an array of objects?

Comment: In this case it returns exactly one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object.keys(obj) to get the keys and use it accordingly.

```js
function parse(item){
     item[Object.keys(item)[0]]["key"]=Object.keys(item)[0];
     return  item[Object.keys(item)[0]];
    }
let test1={
        "0": {
              "prop1": "hello",
              "prob2": "test"
             }
 };
console.log(parse(test1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

let's take for example this

```js
let apiResponse = {
  "0": {
    "prop1": "hello",
    "prob2": "test"
  }
}
```

all you have to do is this

```
let keys = Object.keys(apiResponse)
let data = keys.map(key => ({
   key,
   ...apiResponse[key]
}))
```

Comment: It does not remove the key from the object, it's still `"0": {
    "key":"0,
    "prop1": "hello",
    "prob2": "test"
  }`

Comment: can you show me how do you log the object, I think you have a problem with parsing function